# Filter text through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have:

```
scaffold event_group title status
```

I want to: show event_groups with status: 'scheduled' as a different route.

I tried this, but it does not work because 'scheduled' is text format:

event_groups_controller.rb:

```
  def active
    @event_groups = EventGroup.where(status: 'scheduled')
    render 'index'
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :event_groups do
   get :scheduled, :finished on: :collection
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I get it right. I'm leaving my office. You might try this.

event_groups_controller.rb:

```
def status
  @event_groups = EventGroup.where(status: params[:status])
  render 'index'
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :event_groups do
  get '/:status', to: :status, on: :collection, constraints: { status: /(active)|(forming)|(finished)|(errors)/ }
end
```